# I'm looking for a right solution to achieve the below scenario in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I've a result set from a query like this below

| Court_id | from | to | Available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 6:00:00 | 7:00:00 | Yes |
| 7 | 7:00:00 | 8:00:00 | No |
| 7 | 8:00:00 | 9:00:00 | Yes |
| 8 | 6:00:00 | 7:00:00 | Yes |
| 8 | 7:00:00 | 8:00:00 | Yes |
| 8 | 8:00:00 | 9:00:00 | No |
| 9 | 6:00:00 | 7:00:00 | Yes |
| 9 | 7:00:00 | 8:00:00 | Yes |
| 9 | 8:00:00 | 9:00:00 | No |

How can I achieve in column wise like below from the above result ?

| from | to | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6:00:00 | 7:00:00 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| 7:00:00 | 8:00:00 | no | Yes | Yes |
| 8:00:00 | 9:00:00 | Yes | no | no |

Court_id can change time to time.

I've tried the following

```
CREATE TABLE [testslots](   
    [Court_id] [int] NULL,
    [from]  [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [to]  [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Available] [nvarchar](10) NULL);


INSERT INTO [testslots] ([Court_id] ,[from] ,[to] ,[Available])VALUES (7,'6AM','7AM','Yes');
INSERT INTO [testslots] ([Court_id] ,[from] ,[to] ,[Available])VALUES (7,'7AM','8AM','no');
INSERT INTO [testslots] ([Court_id] ,[from] ,[to] ,[Available])VALUES (7,'8AM','9AM','Yes');
INSERT INTO [testslots] ([Court_id] ,[from] ,[to] ,[Available])VALUES (8,'6AM','7AM','Yes');
INSERT INTO [testslots] ([Court_id] ,[from] ,[to] ,[Available])VALUES (8,'7AM','8AM','Yes');
INSERT INTO [testslots] ([Court_id] ,[from] ,[to] ,[Available])VALUES (8,'8AM','9AM','no');
INSERT INTO [testslots] ([Court_id] ,[from] ,[to] ,[Available])VALUES (9,'6AM','7AM','Yes');
INSERT INTO [testslots] ([Court_id] ,[from] ,[to] ,[Available])VALUES (9,'7AM','8AM','Yes');
INSERT INTO [testslots] ([Court_id] ,[from] ,[to] ,[Available])VALUES (9,'8AM','9AM','no');


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Court_id) 
            FROM [testslots] c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [from],[to], ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select [from]
                    , [to]
                    , [available]
                from testslots
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max([available])
                for available in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pivoting the wrong columns:

```sql
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = STUFF((
            SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Court_id) 
            FROM [testslots] c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,LEN(','),'');

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT
  [from],[to],
  ' + @cols + '
from 
(
    select [from]
         , [to]
         , Court_id
         , available
    from testslots
) x
pivot 
(
    max([available])
    for Court_id in (' + @cols + ')
) p;
';

exec sp_executesql @query;
```